# Mocking DbSet<TEntity> in Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

I want to unit-test the retrieval methods from a repository which has a mocked `DbContext`, but I am not able to set the mocked `DbSet` values to the repository.

**The Repository looks like this:**

```
public class ChangeLogRepository : Repository<ChangeLog>, IChangeLogRepository
{
    public ChangeLogRepository(IDbContext context, long tenantId) : base(context, tenantId)
    {
    }
}
```

**The base class:**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
    protected readonly IDbContext Context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }

    protected Repository(IDbContext context, long tenant)
    {
        Context = context;
        TenantId = tenant;
        Entities = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Entities.ToList();
    }
    //..
}
```

**Last but not least, the test class:**

```
[TestClass]
public class ChangeLogRepository_Test
{
    private ChangeLogRepository repository;
    private List<ChangeLog> allTestData;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        var dbContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
        allTestData = new List<ChangeLog>() {
            new ChangeLog { Id = 10, EntityName = "User",PropertyName = "UserName",PrimaryKeyValue = 1,OldValue = "Max",NewValue = "Moritz",DateChanged = DateTime.Now,FieldType = ChangeLogFieldType.Default },
            new ChangeLog { Id = 10, EntityName = "User",PropertyName = "CreatedAt",PrimaryKeyValue =2,OldValue = "15/06/2017",NewValue = "15/06/2017",DateChanged = DateTime.Now,FieldType = ChangeLogFieldType.Date },
            new ChangeLog { Id = 10, EntityName = "Role",PropertyName = "RoleName",PrimaryKeyValue = 56,OldValue = "Admin",NewValue = "Administrator",DateChanged = DateTime.Now,FieldType = ChangeLogFieldType.Default },
        };
        var changelogs = MockDbSet(allTestData);
        dbContext.Setup(m => m.Set<ChangeLog>()).Returns(() => changelogs);
        repository = new ChangeLogRepository(dbContext.Object, 10);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Setup_Test()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(repository.GetAll(), allTestData);
    }
    private static DbSet<T> MockDbSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class, new()
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryableList = list.AsQueryable();
        Mock<DbSet<T>> dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(queryableList.Provider);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(queryableList.Expression);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(queryableList.ElementType);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableList.GetEnumerator());
        return dbSetMock.Object;
     }
}
```

If I run it, the test fails, because the `getAll()` method retuns null. It seams, that the property 'Entities' wasn't correctly initialized by the mocked `Set()` method.

When I set a breakpoint in the repository-constructor 
and examine the Entities property, under 'Expression > Value > Result View' the three Entries appear. Under the first Result View there are one "Enumeration yielded no results" message and two rows with ? in it (Visual Studio 2017).

**How can I mock the entities in the repository correctly? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the test based exactly on the example provided in the original question and was unable to reproduce the `null` issue. The mock returned a populated collection just as it was configured to do.

A problem occurred however when comparing the two collections,

```
Assert.AreEqual(repository.GetAll(), allTestData);
```

they were not considered equal. Expected, as the `ToList` would be creating a new list which would obviously be a different reference to the original list used as the data source for the mock.

Compare the two collections using `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` instead

```
[TestMethod]
public void Setup_Test() {
    var actual = repository.GetAll();
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(allTestData, actual);
}
```

and the test passes.

Answer (score 1):

The EF documentation covers this.

1. Use `IDbSet<T>` in your context.
2. Create a fake implementation of `IDbSet<T>` for your tests.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314431.

Note there is also a page on using mocking frameworks but I've never done that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.

Note also, if using EF Core (aka EF7) there is an in memory provider avoiding needing doubles at all.